# how to show empty div or null in react using antd?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am getting data from `server` after few seconds on button click. it show me some `white card` for few seconds after button click.

[image]

here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-forest-dmnmj

**problem on this line**

```
const menu = () => {
    return state.length > 0 ? <Menu>{options()}</Menu> : <Menu />;
  };
```

**i tried like this but not working**

```
const menu = () => {
        return state.length > 0 ? <Menu>{options()}</Menu> : <div />;
      };
```

API link
https://ant.design/components/dropdown/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `overlay` property accepts only a `Menu` component.

> overlay   The dropdown menu   Menu | () => Menu

Therefore, you should render some loading indicator:

```
    return state.length > 0 ? (
      <Menu>{options()}</Menu>
    ) : (
      <Menu>
        <Menu.Item disabled>
          <Spin />
        </Menu.Item>
      </Menu>
    );
  };
```

[image: Edit gallant-raman-33ux7]

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Fragment`(https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

```
  const options = (
    <Menu>
    {state.map((i, index) => (
        <Menu.Item key={index}>
          <a href="http://www.alipay.com/">{i}</a>
        </Menu.Item>
      ))};
    </Menu>
  )

 const menu = () => {
    return state.length > 0 ? options : <Fragment />;
  };
```

Edit: After seeing your sandbox. Everything seems to be wrong. Will be back at you

Here's my attempt to fix your code:

```
const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState([]);

  const options = (
    <Menu>
      {state.map((i, index) => (
        <Menu.Item key={index}>
          <a href="http://www.alipay.com/">{i}</a>
        </Menu.Item>
      ))}
    </Menu>
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <Dropdown.Button
        disabled={!(Array.isArray(state) && state.length)}
        overlay={options}
        trigger={["click"]}
        icon={<Icon type="down" />}
      >
        Click me
      </Dropdown.Button>
      <div style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
        <button onClick={() => setState(["Item no. 1", "Item no. 2"])}>
          Add items to list
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => setState([])}>Remove items in list</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Where `disabled={!(Array.isArray(state) && state.length)}` is props from the api itself that disables the component if the list is empty.

I did few tweaks as well by reading the docs (https://ant.design/components/dropdown/#components-dropdown-demo-dropdown-button)

[image: Edit gallant-raman-33ux7]